# Ошибка в задаче со словарями

Tags: python, словари

Известна информация о книгах, поступивших в библиотеку (Автор, цена
количество шт.). Вывести автора, у которого больше всех книг поступило в
библиотеку.

Как исправить в коде ниже ошибку 'int' object has no attribute 'get'?

```
inf = int(input())
d = dict()
for i in range(inf):
    key = input('name: ')
    value = int(input('amount: '))
    d[key] = value
print(max(inf, key=inf.get))
```

Comment: не запустить без inf. Но вы точно inf.get, а не inf.get() хотели?

Comment: так выдает ту же ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что вы хотели получить из словаря ключ, соответствующий наибольшему значению.

#### Что пошло не так?

1. Вы пытаетесь применить метод `get()` от словаря к числовому значению `inf`.
2. Находить максимум только из одного числа - не лучшая затея.

Если мои рассуждения верны, то вам нужно это:

```py
print(max(d, key=d.get))
```